# Regular expression to match optional tokens in any order

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making an URL parser with tokens to filter returned results, theses tokens are optionals and can be set in any order, I just need to get parameters when they are present.

I already made a regex that can get the tokens but the order is important:

```
\/test(\/page\/[0-9]+)?(\/criticality\/[0-9]+)?(\/order\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/eH1bR5/1)

In this example, I would get `/page/1`, `/order/toto` and `/criticality/5` but criticality is not get.

How to get any token in any order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them with positive lookaheads at the beginning of a pattern, and capture the text inside the lookaheads, but you will list all possible combinations of the values which makes a regex solution look ugly:

```
^(?=.*\/test(\/page\/[0-9]+))(?=.*(\/criticality\/[0-9]+))(?=.*(\/order\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+))|^(?=.*\/test(\/page\/[0-9]+))(?=.*(\/order\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+))|^(?=.*\/test(\/page\/[0-9]+))(?=.*(\/criticality\/[0-9]+))|^(?=.*(\/criticality\/[0-9]+))(?=.*(\/order\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+))|^(?=.*(\/criticality\/[0-9]+))|^(?=.*(\/order\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+))|^(?=.*\/test(\/page\/[0-9]+))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mI0lW7/3)

As you see, the regex is not maintainable. You split the input string with `/` and then check if the array contain your keys. If yes, you will get the values that are the element that follows the key.

Comment: Tokens need to be optionals, this method don't allow this.

Comment: Please check my update. Perhaps, regex is not the best option here.

Comment: it works almost, but it match many time the same token, and especially it is not maintainable, here i have only 3 parameters, but in the future i can add others.

Comment: BTW, i think the best way to catch that i want is to get all the string with `\/test([\/a-zA-Z0-9]+)` then parse it manually in javascript.

Comment: Yes, I also see it like splitting the strings, and check against the list of keys you have.

Answer (score 0):

Use alternation operator.

```
\/test(\/page\/[0-9]+)|(\/criticality\/[0-9]+)|(\/order\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eH1bR5/2)

But this would match if anyone of the above is present. It won't expect all the three should be present.

Comment: With this method i get 3 instinct matches, I need only one match with all values (0 to 3 values).